# Javascript intellsense not working in VS2010 Beta 2

Tags: visual-studio

i've just installed the VS2010 premium beta 2 and I can't get javascript intellisense to work.  is there a setting I have to change to enable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2009/10/23/visual-studio-2010-beta-2-intellisense-issue-in-javascript-html.aspx), which should fix your problem.